# sbt equivalent of maven exec plugin

Tags: java, maven, command-line, sbt, program-entry-point

When using maven, you can run the main method of an arbitrary class using [maven exec plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) and `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.example.Main"`. Is there a way to do this in sbt?
The specific use case is that I have a project which is typically a long running service, but I would also like to have some quick command line utilities in the same project which I can start from sbt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sbt "run-main full.class.name"
```

Comment: one question. the jvm does not want to exit at the end of the main method, and explicitly using system exit is caught as `TrapExitSecurityException`. Any suggestions for debugging?

Comment: non-daemon threads will cause the jvm to not exit. but for that matter, sbt runs processes within the current jvm by default, you don't want to System.exit(). if you `fork in run`, then yes, you can System.exit(), otherwise, you must not. If your main isn't returning, then you should break from the loop yourself.

Comment: so there is no loop(in main) (it's a CLI tool). The main method runs, returns, and then it just doesn't exit. Is there some loop in SBT I need to break from?

Comment: if it hangs, your method does not return

Comment: of course, if you're running sbt "run-main ..." from the commandline, and your main class starts non-daemon threads, it will prevent jvm exit until all non-daemon threads have finished.

Comment: The last line of the main is a print statement so I'm confident it returns (no try-finally or anything). The main method does not start any threads, but the main project is a Play framework project, perhaps it starts some threads at static time? Is there a way I can see what threads are running?

Comment: use jstack to list threads, main project is irrelevant, what matters is what main does (directly or not), and it starts threads, otherwise it wouldn't hang.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97448/discussion-between-kag0-and-pfn).

Comment: FYI it's been changed from "run-main" to "runMain" now.